# Using R: Renaming columns in the dataframe

Tags: r, naming

I have just started learning R, but i am having trouble understaning it.

So this is the requested action
"Use the names() command to rename the columns of Mymatr in the data frame."

Mydat <- data.frame(Multof2,Language,mylet,Mymatr,Lessthan15=Multof2<15)
Mydat

names(Mydat)
names

names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3","Mymatr4")
Mydat

and this is what i am receiveing
Mydat
Multof2 Language mylet X1 X2 Lessthan15
1        2  English     A  1 21       TRUE
2        4  English     Z  2 22       TRUE
3        6  English     C  3 23       TRUE
4        8  English     C  4 24       TRUE
5       10  English     Q  5 25       TRUE
6       12    Greek     V  1 26       TRUE
7       14    Greek     C  2 27       TRUE
8       16    Greek     V  3 28      FALSE
9       18    Greek     W  4 29      FALSE
10      20    Greek     A  5 30      FALSE
11      22  English     P  1 31      FALSE
12      24  English     A  2 32      FALSE
13      26  English     E  3 33      FALSE
14      28  English     R  4 34      FALSE
15      30  English     V  5 35      FALSE
16      32    Greek     J  1 36      FALSE
17      34    Greek     Q  2 37      FALSE
18      36    Greek     I  3 38      FALSE
19      38    Greek     W  4 39      FALSE
20      40    Greek     V  5 40      FALSE

> names(Mydat)
> [1] "Multof2"    "Language"   "mylet"      "X1"         "X2"         "Lessthan15"
> names
> function (x)  .Primitive("names")

> names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3","Mymatr4","Mymatr5","Mymatr6","Mymatr7")
> Error in names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1", "Mymatr2", "Mymatr3", "Mymatr4",  :
> 'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [6]
> In addition: Warning message:
> In names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1", "Mymatr2", "Mymatr3", "Mymatr4",  :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3","Mymatr4",)
> Error in c("Mymatr1", "Mymatr2", "Mymatr3", "Mymatr4", ) :
> argument 5 is empty
> names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3","Mymatr4")
> Error in names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1", "Mymatr2", "Mymatr3", "Mymatr4") :
> 'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [6]

> names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3")
> Error in names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1", "Mymatr2", "Mymatr3") :
> 'names' attribute [7] must be the same length as the vector [6]
> In addition: Warning message:
> In names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1", "Mymatr2", "Mymatr3") :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I have tried adding and removing names, as it says that the length is not the same as the vector.

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Thnx

Comment: Hey there! Consider editing your question to highlight the code/pseudocode to make your question more readable. For complete information please check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3","Mymatr4")
```

or

```
library(data.table)

setnames(Mydat, old = c(4:7), new = c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3","Mymatr4"))
```

Comment: This is the answer i get. Shouldn't it rename the rest of them?
   Multof2 Language mylet Mymatr1 X2 Lessthan15
1        2  English     A       1 21       TRUE
2        4  English     Z       2 22       TRUE
3        6  English     C       3 23       TRUE
4        8  English     C       4 24       TRUE
5       10  English     Q       5 25       TRUE
6       12    Greek     V       1 26       TRUE
7       14    Greek     C       2 27       TRUE
8       16    Greek     V       3 28      FALSE
9       18    Greek     W       4 29      FALSE

Comment: @ChristinaPetrou I suspect you're trying to give names to a vector (x) that is shorter than your vector of names (y)

Comment: So basically the exercise is as followed: 2. (a) Create a vector of length 20 with arguments the numbers 2, 4,..., 40. Name the vector ”Multof2”.
(b) Create a vector of length 10, with the first 5 arguments being the word ”English” and
the remaining 5 arguments being the word ”Greek”. Name it ”Language”. Make it a factor.
(c) Create a sample of size 20 from the capital letters of the alphabet with replacement. Call it ”mylet”.

Comment: (d) Create the vector below using rep.
(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40). Make it a matrix with two columns and name the matrix ”Mymatr”.
(e) Create a data frame with columns the objects you created in questions 2 to 5, and an additional column giving TRUE or FALSE if the corresponding ”Multof2” value is less than 15. Call the data frame ”Mydat”.
(f) Explain the names given to the columns of matrix Mymatr in the data frame.
(g) Use the names() command to rename the columns of Mymatr in the data frame.

Comment: The script in R i wrote is:# 2 (a)
Multof2 <- seq(2,40,by=2)

# 2 (b)
Language <- c(rep("English",5),rep("Greek",5))
Language <- factor(Language)
Language

# 2 (c)
mylet <- sample(LETTERS,20,replace = TRUE)

# 2 (d)
Mymatr <- c(rep(1:5,4),21:40)
dim(Mymatr) <- c(20,2) # OR Mymatr <- matrix(Mymatr, ncol=2)

# 2 (e)
Mydat <- data.frame(Multof2,Language,mylet,Mymatr,Lessthan15=Multof2<15)
Mydat

# 2 (g)
names(Mydat)[4:7] <- c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3","Mymatr4")
Mydat
Am i understanding this wrong?

Comment: @ChristinaPetrou  You are using wrong index   ```names(Mydat)[3:6] <- c("Mymatr1","Mymatr2","Mymatr3","Mymatr4")```  If i am able to understand you properly, this will work.

Comment: thank you so much. So much to learn in this program and i want to understand everything at the beginning before it gets too complicated for me. :) i appreciate the time you spent!